# Дерево Фенвика, разбор доказательства корректности

Tags: алгоритм, дерево

Всем привет!
По ссылке [дерево Фенвика](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&oldid=47028) есть разбор алгоритма дерева Фенвика и я никак не могу понять следующий переход, не могли бы вы мне, пожалуйста, подсказать почему это так? (формулы не вставляются, но абзац найти можно)

> Но если *j*<sub>0</sub> < *k*<sub>0</sub>, то и *j* ⩽ *k*, что противоречит условию *j* > *k*. Значит, *j*<sub>0</sub> = *k*<sub>0</sub>. Но тогда *j* возможно получить по формуле *i*<sub>*next*</sub> = *i*<sub>*prev*</sub> | (*i*<sub>*prev*</sub> + 1). Получили противоречие, следовательно, *F*(*j*) > *k*. Таким образом, нужные элементы можно искать по формуле *i*<sub>*next*</sub> = *i*<sub>*prev*</sub> | (*i*<sub>*prev*</sub> + 1).

Не понимаю из чего следуют что *j* можно получить по формуле которую мы и доказываем, там следует это из *j*<sub>0</sub> = *k*<sub>0</sub>, но что-то это нифига не очевидно.

Comment: Вставляются, если сильно захотеть.

Comment: Очень круто что на стэке даже на такие вопросы отвечают! Благодарю :)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Вообще-то это вопрос по дискретной математике, так что более подходящим форумом был бы маткод, например. Тем не менее, программистам эта тема тоже интересна!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле всё просто.

Пусть *j* имеет в двоичной записи вид `******01111...1`, тогда *j*<sub>0</sub> имеет вид `******0` (то же без финальных единиц). По доказанному, *j*<sub>0</sub> = *k*<sub>0</sub>, значит, *k* начинается с тех же цифр, что и *j*, и имеет вид

```
j = ******01111...1   (1)
k = ******0????...?   (2)
```

(Цифры под звёздочками в (1) и (2) поразрядно равны.) То есть под финальными единицами *j* расположены какие-то цифры (0 или 1) *k*, а под нулём, который идёт перед этими единицами — также ноль.

Теперь, что делает операция *x* → *x* | (*x* + 1)? Она в двоичной записи числа *x* заменяет самый младший 0 на 1. (Это очевидно? Если нет, доказательство ниже.)

Таким образом, если мы начнём от числа *k* и будет применять эту операцию, то мы последовательно превратим все нули, лежащие правее нуля в представлении (2), в единицы. После этого числа сверху и снизу ((1) и (2)), очевидно, сравняются. Итак, мы доказали, что *j* можно получить из *k* при помощи рассматриваемой операции.

---

**Дополнение:**

Лемма: операция *x* → *x* | (*x* + 1) в двоичной записи числа *x* заменяет самый младший 0 на 1.

Доказательство. Пусть двоичная запись *x* имеет вид

```
*******01111...1    (3)
```

Тогда, исходя из алгоритма сложения в столбик, двоичная запись числа *x* + 1 имеет вид

```
*******10000...0    (4)
```

(причём двоичные цифры в (3), обозначенные звёздочками, *совпадают* с двоичными цифрами в (4) на тех же местах). А значит, число *x* | (*x* + 1) имеет вид

```
*******01111...1    \ побитовое
*******10000...0    /    или
----------------
*******11111...1
```

Что и требовалось доказать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробное объяснение, перед этим в итоге после осмысления к тому же пришел, а вы подтвердили. :) Еще маленький вопрос, я правильно понял что в фразе "Покажем, почему не стоит рассматривать значения , отличные от тех, которые мы получили по формуле." имелось ввиду что мы возьмем j > k и ожидаем что его нельзя будет получить по формуле, а в результате доказательства приходим как раз к противоречию что его можно получить?

Comment: @Михаил: Именно так. То есть реально утверждение доказывает, что все _j_ можно получить при помощи операции, _начиная с k_.